# How to open only one window popup

Tags: javascript

**script.js**

```
function openWin() {
   var prop = "left=500, width=450, height=450";
   var myWindow = window.open('', '', prop);
}
```

**html file**

```
<a href="#" onclick="openWin()">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" onclick="openWin()">Link 2</a>
```

I want after multi click then just only one open popup window. Please hepl me.

Comment: So you want the older pop-up to be refreshed instead of opening a new one?

Comment: I want after click then close old pop-up and open new pop-up.

Comment: Give the window a [windowName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting a name param and using all the time the same value:

```
var myWindow = window.open('', 'someName', prop);
```

Notice the parameter with *someName* value. Should have the same value all the time for the window to be reused.

**UPDATE**

And a link to [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) as @gurvinder372 suggested: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Comment: This is the right answer, please include the documentation link for reference as well. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open